# applying clipping mask to multiple objects

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I want to apply a brush splash to the central petals of the flower. But clipping mask doesn't work. It says object is too complex. The only way I found to resolve this problem is using shape builder tool and cut every single petal in order to avoid outlines overlapping.  Then make a copy of petals with fill and place a brush splash between outlines and fill layer. I wonder is there any less time consuming solution ? The main problem is outlines, they overlapping each other without a fill. Opacity mask doesn't adress my problem, because I don't want the outlines to be covered by a brush splash. The brush splash have to be inside of each petal. Thank you !
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I realize the duplicate link may not *seem* like a duplicate. However, you need an **Opacity Mask**, *not* a clipping mask. and the duplicate explains how to create an opacity mask in Illustrator. So, while *technically* not a duplicate, it will solve your problem.

Comment: It didn't help or i did something wrong . I need a splash to be placed UNDER the outlines, it shouldn't cover outlines.  But opacity mask placing it on the top of everything. Please see the screenshot updated in the first post. And I need to be able to change the colour of the splash

Comment: Please remove duplicate mark.

Comment: Okay reopened. I still feel an opacity mask is warranted, but you may need to configure the artwork for the mask to work as you desire.

Comment: I think I found a solution, if you choose colour as transparency mode, it bypasses the blacks and fills only inside of the object

Comment: or you could set the layer structure so the keyline (black) is above other objects.

Comment: It won't work because, objects will be overlapping. Screen provided in the first post. But anyways, other solution working perfectly.